# Loading a child view in a headless browser using Awesomium

Tags: c#, awesomium, headless-browser

I built a C# console application that creates a `WebView` (Awesomium 1.7.4) and loads some dynamic pages and takes their screenshot.

Everything is working great.
The problem begins when I added an handler to the `ShowCreatedWebView` [Event](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowCreatedWebView) which occurs when a new view is requested.

In my case its a form submit which loads a file download page.

After adding the handler I get an error while waiting for the first `WebView`

> The WebCore is not initialized

The parts that matters in my code:

Handlers:

```
...

WebCore.Download += onDownload;
webView.ShowCreatedWebView += onDownloadRequest;
webView.LoadingFrameComplete += (sender, e) =>
{
     FrameHasError = false;
     finishedLoading = true;
};
webView.LoadingFrame += (sender, e) =>
{
     FrameHasError = false;
     finishedLoading = false;
};
webView.LoadingFrameFailed += loadingFailed;

....
```

The `ShowCreatedWebView` handler:

```
private static void onDownloadRequest(object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView webDownload = new WebView(e.NewViewInstance);
        webDownload.Resize(1024, 768);

        // Expecting a white picture but nothing is saved webDownload.Surface is null!?
        surface = (BitmapSurface)webDownload.Surface;
        surface.SaveToPNG(opt_target + "testNewView.png", true);
    }
```

The main `WebView` at the point where the `ShowCreatedWebView` is triggered:

```
...

finishedLoading = false;
string jsActionDownloadFiles = HelperParser.jsLibActions("trigger-download-files");
//Triggers the form submit on the page:
webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult(jsActionDownloadFiles); //FIRES ShowCreatedWebView 
while (!finishedLoading)
{
    Thread.Sleep(Waits["web-loading"]);
    WebCore.Update(); //ERROR OCCURS HERE AFTER THE ShowCreatedWebView FIRES
}

...
```

Any idea what I'm missing??